# Dragging a group in canvas using kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

I have an application based on html5 Canvas. I have used kineticjs library for dragging-dropping. It has multiple groups for drag and drop.
If I increases canvas size to larger size it has lag in dragging.
how can we improve dragging performance. It can easily notice on iPad and Tablet devices.
I have created a sample. 
jsfiddle.net/MRVCg/5/embedded/result/

Comment: while I do not notice a performance result on even my phone (which has less memory and slower processor than most iPads/tablets), you can always do caching. Can you post some more code than the given example? Any slow-down would be caused by events which are running while you are doing dragging. Are you doing any checking on drag move?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a valid question,

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-shape-caching-with-kineticjs/

You should try caching your shapes as images for better performance. You can do so with:

```
shape.toImage({
  // define the size of the new image object
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  callback: function(img) {
    // cache the image as a Kinetic.Image shape
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: img
    };
  }
});
```